# Android espresso dagger tests. Mocking in constructor injection

Tags: mocking, dagger-2

I have an activity and injected presenter through constructor injection. Something like this

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    RegistrationPresenter registrationPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SampleApplication.instance.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
}


public class RegistrationPresenter {
    @Inject
    public RegistrationPresenter{
    } 
}
```

I am trying to mock a presenter and inject it in an activity. But it works only if a presenter is provided in Module. How can I mock and inject my presenter?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe create a different flavor for `mock` presenters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's posible since Android 9,
[check this article](https://medium.com/default-to-open/android-pie-and-the-future-of-dependency-injection-2fdbc65cb79b)

In older versions you need to create separate component for test.

```
class TestApplication : MyApplication() {
    override val component: TestComponent by lazy {
        DaggerTestComponent.builder().applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this)).build()
    }
}
```

custom runner:

```
class TestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    @Throws(InstantiationException::class, IllegalAccessException::class, ClassNotFoundException::class)
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, context: Context): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

and runner registration in `build.gradle` file:

```
 defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.package.TestRunner"
    }
```

In `TestComponent` you can now attach module with test implementation of `RegistrationPresenter`